# How to pass type as parameter?

Tags: typescript

I have the duplicate part of code that I want to move in separated function:

```
 for (var i = allActions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (allActions[i] instanceof EditablePolygon) {
                    this.currentAction = allActions[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
```

This code depends on type `EditablePolygon`. Could I pass this type as parameter in function?

```
function iterate(type: T) {
     for (var i = allActions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (allActions[i] instanceof T) {
                        this.currentAction = allActions[i];
                        break;
                    }
}
            }
```

Comment: TS is erased from runtime, so you cannot pass types as function arguments.

Comment: How to avoid DRY then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Consider the following:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAKAhqkQLZJQQAewECAJpahEQ4gDYhREIgDaAXSgBeKCzaduvAYIA0UAEoQk6DsFE8+APlEBYAFBQoCCAHcoACgB0tsCXJIAXFGKkKASlG7lq9QG5DQwAzdARsAEtEKGCIxgBJZGBeTGg8GBxUKlp6JlhEFAxsXG1LElIQFwl2BC4oMIBrBDgzBCEFTAK0LEyXDNwPF0SUFIgAFXAIdMzdAB96xghY0wYoAG9DY2DcK06kqAA3Ig50aDhgnlQKrw2jYygIi8sjk+g4kfCIc6g9wp6B8QQYDoVAIQ7HU6BO4AX02gOBoIWDCWcQgDChsIMQA)

```ts
type Constructor<Params extends readonly any[] = readonly any[], Result = any> =
  new (...params: Params) => Result;

function findInstance <Ctor extends Constructor>(array: readonly unknown[], constructor: Ctor): InstanceType<Ctor> | undefined {
  for (const value of array) {
    if (value instanceof constructor) return value;
  }
  return undefined;
}
```